# C# library to authenticate users against your own database, facebook, twitter, OpenID, 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, open-source

I am looking for an open-source C# library with flexible licencing to use in an ASP.NET MVC application.

It should be able to authenticate users against a local database, facebook, twitter, OpenID or other popular authentication methods.

Is there such a library available?

Comment: Aren't facebook and twitter just OpenID relay parties?

Comment: They are but not all facebook or twitter users have an OpenID account.

Comment: Cool, didn't realize that existed, live and learn.

Answer (score 10):

This is exactly what one of the goals of [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351) is. It allows you to abstract your authentication code away with different providers. They have a very complete [developer training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3e315fa-94e2-4028-99cb-904369f177c0),  and there are modules avaiable to authenticate with all kinds of different protocols (OpenID, OAuth, Facebook, LiveID...) or you can use [ACS](http://acs.codeplex.com/) to provide the abstraction around all the different protocols.

For even more information see these:

- http://claimsid.codeplex.com/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/IdentityTrainingCourse

Comment: Wow, that's awesome.  Is it not publicized heavily or have I just been living under a rock?

Comment: Hah! Yeah, I would say it's rather unheard of in the general ASP.NET realm. I think its more well known in "internal/corporate apps" as it works *wonderfully* with ADFS. I hope it becomes more popular as I think claims based auth is going to be big.

Comment: How would ACS work with twitter? It's not out of the box~!

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is a library that could work against all the possible sites you can list. You could use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) for OpenID.