# DotNetOpenAuth and Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

Does anyone know of any code samples on how to use DotNetOpenAuth with Facebook using ASP.NET MVC 3 (or any version of MVC for that matter)? The samples that come with the library do not have any Facebook examples (it looks like they used to according to some posts but not anymore).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related question: [C# library to authenticate users against your own database, facebook, twitter, OpenID, ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292572/c-library-to-authenticate-users-against-your-own-database-facebook-twitter-op/5292789)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook uses OAuth 2.0 instead of OpenID for logins, so you must download the [DotNetOpenAuth CTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/) in order to get the Facebook login sample.  And the sample isn't for MVC, it's for web forms.  But since it's all code in the code-behind anyway, you hopefully can make the translation yourself.

Comment: This answer provides a nice walkthrough of DotNetOpenAuth and Facebook using the CTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth/5259556#5259556

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have your heart set on [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/), you could also take a look at [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351).  It also supports OAuth 2.0 and Will give you the flexibility to use other authentication providers.